# Scala choose which trait to implement from in case of conflicting signatures?

Tags: java, scala, oop, multiple-inheritance, traits

How to choose in Scala which trait to choose implementation from in case of conflicting method signatures?

Suppose the following Java interfaces:

```
interface Dog {
    default void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }

    default void beHappy() {
        System.out.println("Wag tail");
    }
}

interface Cat {
    default void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }

    default void beHappy() {
        System.out.println("Purrr");
    }
}
```

And now suppose I want a purring dog, without reimplementing anything:

```
public class PurringDog implements Dog, Cat {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        Dog.super.makeSound();
    }

    @Override
    public void beHappy() {
        Cat.super.beHappy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PurringDog purringDog = new PurringDog();

        purringDog.makeSound(); //prints Woof
        purringDog.beHappy();   //prints Purrr
    }
}
```

How can this be achieved in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use super with a qualifier:

```scala
trait Dog {
  def makeSound(): Unit = println("Woof")
  def beHappy(): Unit = println("Wag tail")
}

trait Cat {
  def makeSound(): Unit = println("Meow")
  def beHappy(): Unit = println("Purrr")
}

class PurringDog extends Dog with Cat {
  override def makeSound() = super[Dog].makeSound()
  override def beHappy() = super[Cat].beHappy()
}

object Test extends App {
  val purringDog = new PurringDog
  purringDog.beHappy()
  purringDog.makeSound()
}
```

Note that you can use the qualifier only for the traits you mix in directly (those appearing after an `extends` or a `with`), so crawling on the hierarchy (e.g. having a base trait `Animal`) won't work with qualifiers.